# C# (WinForms) - Как сохранить данные авторизации(VkNet)?

Tags: c#, winforms, vkontakte-api, vknet

Недавно начал изучать VkNet, сделал авторизацию - успешно, но понадобилось сделать так, чтобы авторизация была во всех формах, то есть если человек авторизировался в специальной для авторизации форме, ему не нужно было авторизироваться в других, и те формы выполняли нужные функции VK API.
Вот код:

```
VkApi Vk = new VkApi();
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ulong appID = ...;
        string login = textBox3.Text;
        string password = textBox4.Text;
        Settings settings = Settings.All;


        Vk.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
        {
            ApplicationId = appID,
            Login = login,
            Password = password,
            Settings = settings,
        });
    }
```

Comment: Сделайте менеджера,который будет отвечать за все действия с ВК и подсовывайте во все окна

Comment: Используйте свойства статического класса для обмена информацией между формами.

Comment: @BabaYaga пытался, не получалось

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто передавать экземпляр класса VkApi как параметр конструктора всех классов окон, в которых вы собираетесь работать с ним. Там записывать его в поле, и обращаться уже к нему.